# Internal Server Error Django/apache

Tags: django, apache, python-2.7, centos7

My Django app was working fine, but now I'm getting a server error, the last thing I did was a reboot to my Centos7 Server and now I'm getting this error:
[image]
and this are my logs I'm using apache:

```
[Thu Mar 30 14:04:10.571843 2017] [:error] [pid 11335] [remote 10.221.50.100:24] mod_wsgi (pid=11335): Target WSGI script '/opt/btsystem/BTSystem/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
    [Thu Mar 30 14:04:10.571991 2017] [:error] [pid 11335] [remote 10.221.50.100:24] mod_wsgi (pid=11335): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/btsystem/BTSystem/wsgi.py'.
    [Thu Mar 30 14:04:10.572263 2017] [:error] [pid 11335] [remote 10.221.50.100:24] Traceback (most recent call last):
    [Thu Mar 30 14:04:10.572544 2017] [:error] [pid 11335] [remote 10.221.50.100:24]   File "/opt/btsystem/BTSystem/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    [Thu Mar 30 14:04:10.572795 2017] [:error] [pid 11335] [remote 10.221.50.100:24]     application = get_wsgi_application()
    [Thu Mar 30 14:04:10.572919 2017] [:error] [pid 11335] [remote 10.221.50.100:24]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    [Thu Mar 30 14:04:10.573054 2017] [:error] [pid 11335] [remote 10.221.50.100:24]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
    [Thu Mar 30 14:04:10.573107 2017] [:error] [pid 11335] [remote 10.221.50.100:24]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 22, in setup
    [Thu Mar 30 14:04:10.573170 2017] [:error] [pid 11335] [remote 10.221.50.100:24]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
    [Thu Mar 30 14:04:10.573261 2017] [:error] [pid 11335] [remote 10.221.50.100:24]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 75, in configure_logging
    [Thu Mar 30 14:04:10.573312 2017] [:error] [pid 11335] [remote 10.221.50.100:24]     logging_config_func(logging_settings)
    [Thu Mar 30 14:04:10.573369 2017] [:error] [pid 11335] [remote 10.221.50.100:24]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 803, in dictConfig
    [Thu Mar 30 14:04:10.573409 2017] [:error] [pid 11335] [remote 10.221.50.100:24]     dictConfigClass(config).configure()
    [Thu Mar 30 14:04:10.573455 2017] [:error] [pid 11335] [remote 10.221.50.100:24]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 585, in configure
    [Thu Mar 30 14:04:10.573501 2017] [:error] [pid 11335] [remote 10.221.50.100:24]     '%r: %s' % (name, e))
    [Thu Mar 30 14:04:10.573567 2017] [:error] [pid 11335] [remote 10.221.50.100:24] ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file': [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/btsystem-logs/btsystem-debug.log'
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was that I needed to do the following to enable the virtual host from Apache:

```
firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Needed to open the ports.

Answer (score 1):

The last line shows that Django doesn't have permission to write to the configured log file.

`[Thu Mar 30 14:04:10.573567 2017] [:error] [pid 11335] [remote 10.221.50.100:24] ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file': [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/btsystem-logs/btsystem-debug.log'`

Make sure the file `/opt/btsystem-logs/btsystem-debug.log` is writeable by the user running the Django server.

Comment: I already did, i did chmod 777 to that path and still having this issue.

Comment: @Deluq Does everything else work if you disable logging?

Comment: I just found the solution

Comment: Or better still, do not using the logging module to log to a separate file. Set it up to log to the console stream handler which means log output gets sent to the Apache error log for the host. Using the Apache log file is the more typical way of doing it.